# How to modify tables of a model (without controller) from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a model GeneralCourses that I want to update from a controller Courses. I want to be able to add and edit entries in the model GenralCourses.

The issue I am having now is that when I want to submit the form it tells me:
`No route matches [POST] "/courses/create"`

courses_controller:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @course = GeneralCourse.new
    end

    def create
        @course = GeneralCourse.new(contact_params)

        if @course.save
            flash[:success] = "Course created"
            redirect_to new_course_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Announcement not uploaded"
            redirect_to new_course_path
        end
    end

    def update

    end

    private

        def contact_params
            params.require(:general_course).permit(:course_code, :course_title, :course_unit, :course_desc)
        end
end
```

courses form:

```
<%= form_for '/courses/create', method: :POST do |f| %>
with the form fields
<%= end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :admins
    devise_for :staffs
    devise_for :students
    resources :courses
    resources :announcements
    resources :school_calenders
    resources :pages
    get '/stud/timetable' => 'pages#timetable'
    get '/login' => 'pages#login'
    get '/stud/announcement' => 'pages#ann'
    root 'pages#home'
end
```

Comment: (1) please show your `routes.rb` file content, (2) assuming you've set up conventional routes, you should probably do `form_for courses_path`, (3) by convention, a `post` is usually done to `/courses` which is typically routed to the `create` action - not `/courses/create`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out from your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it looks like you're using conventional routes for `courses`, you should be able to do:

```
<%= form_for courses_path do |f| %>
  ... with the form fields
<% end %>
```

Now, given also that in your `new` action, you did:

```
def new
  @course = GeneralCourse.new
end
```

Then you really ought to be able to do:

```
<%= form_for @course do |f| %>
  ... with the form fields
<% end %>
```

Now, if you make your form into a partial, you should be able to use the same partial for your `new` action and your `edit` action.